How to read this three phase circuit?

There are three phase load and 3 single phase loads. The network parameters: $$V_{line}=416<30^\circ[V] rms,60 Hz$$
I'm asked to find the neutral current which exists since the system is not balanced due to mixing three and single phase loads. The loads themselves are balanced. The three phase load is at delta configuration.
We didn't learn at all how to deal with this kind of problems. I don't even know how to read this, where are the currents and voltages. This is the kinds of problems we learned in class:

I can solve these problems because I can read the circuit. When the problem is written as some kind of network, and not a clear electric circuit I don't understand how to approach it. I tried to transform it but I'm not sure if it's true:


To determine the neutral current, \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{N}\$, for the given system, we need to calculate the individual currents in phases \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{AN}\$, \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{BN}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{CN}\$ based on the loads, and then combine them vectorially since the system is unbalanced.
Given:

Line Voltage (RMS): \$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{line}=416\space\angle\space30^\circ\text{V}\$
The phase-to-neutral voltage is (RMS):
$$\text{V}_\text{phase}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{line}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\displaystyle416}{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}\tag1$$
Three-phase load: \$\displaystyle36\space\text{kW}\$, \$\text{PF}=0.5\space\text{lagging}\$ (Delta configuration)
Single-phase loads:
$$\text{P}_\text{A-street}=48\space\text{kW},\text{PF}_\text{A-street}=1\tag2$$
$$\text{P}_\text{B-street}=30\space\text{kW},\text{PF}_\text{B-street}=1\tag3$$
$$\text{P}_\text{C-street}=60\space\text{kW},\text{PF}_\text{C-street}=1\tag4$$

Each single-phase load is connected phase-to-neutral:
$$\text{I}_\text{AN}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{A-street}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{phase}\cdot\text{PF}_\text{A-street}}=\frac{48000}{\frac{\displaystyle416}{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}\cdot1}=\frac{\displaystyle1500\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle13}\space\text{A}\tag5$$
Since the \$\displaystyle\text{PF}_\text{A-street}=1\$, the current is in phase with the voltage \$\text{I}_\text{AN}\space\angle\space0^\circ\$.
$$\text{I}_\text{BN}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{B-street}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{phase}\cdot\text{PF}_\text{B-street}}=\frac{30000}{\frac{\displaystyle416}{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}\cdot1}=\frac{\displaystyle1875\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle26}\space\text{A}\tag7$$
With \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{BN}\space\angle\space-120^\circ\$ relative to \$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{phase}\$.
$$\text{I}_\text{CN}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{C-street}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{phase}\cdot\text{PF}_\text{C-street}}=\frac{60000}{\frac{\displaystyle416}{\displaystyle\sqrt{3}}\cdot1}=\frac{\displaystyle1875\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle13}\space\text{A}\tag7$$
With \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{CN}\space\angle\space120^\circ\$ relative to \$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{phase}\$.
For the delta load, calculate the total line current contribution. The apparent power per phase is:
$$\text{S}_\text{phase}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{total power}}{\displaystyle3}=\frac{\displaystyle36000}{\displaystyle3}=12\space\text{kVA}\tag8$$
So:
$$\text{I}_\text{line, delta}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{S}_\text{phase}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{line}}=\frac{\displaystyle12000}{\displaystyle416}=\frac{\displaystyle375}{\displaystyle13}\tag9$$
Since the \$\displaystyle\text{PF}=0.5\$ lagging, the phase angle is:
$$\arccos\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle2}\right)=60^\circ\tag{10}$$
The currents on each line are \$\displaystyle60^\circ\$ lagging behind the respective phase voltages:
$$\text{I}_\text{A}=\frac{\displaystyle375}{\displaystyle13}\space\angle\space-60^\circ,\space\text{I}_\text{B}=\frac{\displaystyle375}{\displaystyle13}\space\angle-180\space^\circ,\space\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{\displaystyle375}{\displaystyle13}\space\angle\space60^\circ\tag{11}$$
Now, answering the question we get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\text{I}_\text{N}\right|_\text{RMS}&=\left|\text{I}_\text{AN}+\text{I}_\text{BN}+\text{I}_\text{CN}\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle1500\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle13}\space\angle\space0^\circ+\frac{\displaystyle1875\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle26}\space\angle\space-120^\circ+\frac{\displaystyle1875\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle13}\space\angle\space120^\circ\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle375\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle52}+\frac{\displaystyle5625}{\displaystyle52}\cdot\text{j}\right|\\
\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\displaystyle375\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle52}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\displaystyle5625}{\displaystyle52}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle375\sqrt{57}}{\displaystyle26}\\
\\
&\approx108.892\space\text{A}
\end{split}\tag{12}
\end{equation}
